# How to redirect properly using htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect with rewrite rules in Apache - .htaccess. I had set of rules which worked fine for redirection all http:// to https://.

So if the user try http://www.example-old.com, http://example-old.com, http://www.example-new.com or http://example-new.com, all of this will be redirected to https://example-new.com

Now I want to add one more address on the server which I do NOT want to be redirected to https://example-new.com

So I want it to be excluded from the code below. If somebody try http://newest-example.com it should redirect to it properly.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example-new.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What I tried in addition to the code above is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newest-example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newest-example.com [R=301,S=1]
```

This code is above the first block I presented. Like you can see I tried to skip original RewriteRule with S=1 if URL is http://newest-example.com but that gives me this message:

```
Moved Permanently

The document has moved here.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Not that experienced with this and I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an exclusion rule in your first rule itself:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^newest-example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example-new.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Just tried that and my server triggered 500 error. Even my original site was down. Suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log and tell me what is causing 500

Comment: This is what got: 

`www.8stepadmission.com [Fri Apr 03 04:21:42 2015] [error] [client 59.154.251.221] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Comment: Actually this is the error: `public_html/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters`

Comment: There are no bad flags since I tested this rule on my Apache. Make sure you have everything as shown here. There should be any extra space inside `[` and `]`

Comment: Yup, the solution works, I had an extra space "!^ newest...". It's funny how I tried this rule before and didn't work probably due the same problem. Thank you for your time and help.